# Another "Foundation icons not display in Heroku Rails 4" post

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation

I've found several threads addressing issues with foundation icons not displaying in production environments but displaying fine in development. I've followed the directions and solutions in each of them including trying [this gem](https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails) and most recently without this gem by using [this post](http://dsully360.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/using-foundation-icon-fonts-in-rails/) yet I am still unable to get the icons in production.

The fonts seem to be getting fingerprinted properly when precompiling assets but Heroku seems to be looking in the wrong place. Here is an example one of the errors from the Heroku logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/foundation-icons.ttf"):
```

I've tried with and without adding this to my application.css.scss file:

```
@import 'foundation-icons';

@font-face {
    font-family: "foundation-icons";
    src: font-url( asset-path("foundation-icons.eot") );
    src: font-url( asset-path("foundation-icons.eot?#iefix") )   format("embedded-opentype"),
     font-url( asset-path("foundation-icons.woff") ) format("woff"),
     font-url( asset-path("foundation-icons.ttf") ) format("truetype"),
     font-url( asset-path("foundation-icons.svg#fontcustom") ) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  }
```

I'm really stumped by this.

Comment: Update: The issue I was having was that  the devise secret key was not available in production. I found this out by running rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production. I just need to add the key to the devise initializer when I want to precompile.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved when I added the css-directory including the icons to my assets path in `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app/assets/stylesheets/foundation-icons')
```

Another way to do this is `*= require_directory ./foundation-icons` inside your application.css assuming the icon-directory sits inside app/assets/stylesheets